# Django view Site as another user from admin without knowing/resetting password

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way in Django for the admin to view site as another user.

This can be used to debug user specific bugs.

As we don't know the password, the only solution I found is to reset the password from djangoadmin and login it to that user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django user impersonation by admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242909/django-user-impersonation-by-admin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality is not built-in to django, fortunately like many such cases, the community is there to help.

[`django-hijack`](https://github.com/arteria/django-hijack/) does what you require:

> django-hijack allows superusers to hijack (=login as) and work on
>   behalf of another user.